# Nuclear physics study materials

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, nuclear-engineering

I'm currently a ChemE undergraduate student and wish to pursue masters in nuclear engineering. Can you suggest some introductory reading material so that I can get acquainted with nuclear engineering and figure out whether it's right for me or not.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437765/149907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest "Introduction to Nuclear Engineering" by John Lamarsh. The text is aimed at juniors and seniors with no previous training in nuclear engineering. It starts at quite a low level, even introducing the fundamental particles, concepts of particle wavelength related to particle energy etc.  It is mainly concerned with nuclear reactors as that is where nuclear engineers mainly work.

Answer (score 0):

Lamarsh is a great textbook, but a little dated and out-of-print.  You can usually pick up copies on E-Bay.

The book currently used in many junior-level nuclear engineering courses is E. E. Lewis, "Fundamentals of Nuclear Engineering", Elsevier (2008).
ISBN 978-0-12-370631-7