# Nuclear physics complete books

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I have a Master's degree in Theoretical physics, and I've followed a university course on Nuclear Physics. I want to study the subject in more detail. I'm looking for a complete, but a not introductory, book where I can find both theoretical and experimental descriptions about Nuclear Physics. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437765/2451 and links therein.

Comment: In that link, only Krane's book was suggested. As I said, I'm looking for a more advanced and detailed, but complete, book on Nuclear physics...