# Resource recommendation for Introduction to Nuclear Physics

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I am taking an introductory class in Nuclear and Particle Physics, and although my professor is following Krane's Introduction to Nuclear Physics, I'd like to know what alternatives are out there that I could use to study for this class, that are somewhat similar to Krane.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437765/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. That person was looking for books to learn about elementary nuclear physics so they can understand nuclear weapons, I'm looking for books on nuclear and particle physics on an academic level. Not to mention the accepted response was Krane's book, and I'm specifically asking for alternatives to it.