# Nuclear Physics textbooks with full solutions to all the exercises

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, education

Can anyone recommend a nuclear physics textbook which is focused on theory rather than engineering and comes with full solutions to all the problems provided in a separate solutions manual.

I MUST have a full solution manual. It may be an introductory text or advanced. Either way I can use it.

My query is very specific and there is no duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Introduction to nuclear physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437765/)

Comment: @Amit It does not. I am interested in theory and I need full solutions for self-study.

Comment: So you might want to emphasize that you've looked through the existing resource recommendations posts (there are quite a few) on the subject and none of the books there meet the criteria you're looking for. This is just a tip, so this won't get closed as a duplicate...

Comment: Hi @SomeStudent. Res. recom. qs usually don't look at prices, so I removed that part.

Comment: If you are an instructor at a university, you should contact the publisher of a book you are interested in to see if the solution manual exists. If you are a student, you shouldn't have it because it's intended for instructors to have as a guide.

Comment: "you shouldn't have it" does not exist in my dictionary. How I study is my business especially when I'm paying.

Comment: Hey, if the instructors are allowed to have them because they can't figure it out on their own, how are students supposed to solve it?

Comment: This seems like a misguided question. You really don’t care if the book is introductory or advanced? That seems much more important. Is there a specific topic you want the book to get to?

Comment: There is for example "Modern Particle Physics" by Thomson. It's introductory by I found it quite challenging. It comes with a Solutions Manual without which I would have not solved some problems because they required knowledge that wasn't covered in the text. I am looking for that but about Nuclear physics. Krane looks ok but solutions manual does not exist for it. I am starting to think no such textbook exists.

Comment: *How I study is my business especially when I'm paying* Accurate, but how a publishing company makes money and deals with trust issues (i.e., how does a publisher avoid issues relating to copyright infringement and academic dishonesty) is *their* business, not yours.

Comment: You do have a point, my friend, but it's irrelevant. The problem is not so much how to obtain a copy of a solutions manual for some nuclear physics text book. The problem is, does one even exist?

Answer (score 1):

Although other posts have plenty of recommendations of good books But since you are asking with a book with all exercises solved,

[DC Tayal Nuclear Physics](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Nuclear_Physics.html?id=Ok6DAQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) this book explains the concepts fairly and
You can find the the solution manual (which is written in scilab but by hand calculation are obvious too) [here](https://scilab.in/textbook_companion/generate_book/1970)

I would recommend to also keep other books as references as well like [Krane](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Introductory_Nuclear_Physics.html?id=hn2zzgEACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)

You might also want to study the angular momentum techniques for **Advanced Nuclear** physics you can look into [Angular Momentum techniques by Devanathan](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-306-47123-X) which also provide solutions at back for selected exercises other books without solution are already mentioned in other posts, you can take them as references as well.

Comment: how do i get this Tayals book

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Nuclear-Physics-D-C-Tayal/dp/935097830X

Answer (score -3):

Chegg.com has solutions for this book:

Introductory Nuclear Physics
David Halliday, Kenneth S Krane
(1987)

https://www.chegg.com/textbooks/introductory-nuclear-physics-3rd-edition-9780471805533-047180553x

You might find other books on the topic with solutions on Chegg.com.

When you search for a book name it says "Solutions available" under the book info if the book in question has solutions.

(But in some cases, the solutions could be partial.)

It looks to be this book on Amazon (but you might want to double check that the editions match):

[https://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Nuclear-Physics-Kenneth-Krane/dp/8126517859](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8126517859)

Another book with at least partial solutions on Chegg.com is:

https://www.chegg.com/textbooks/fundamentals-of-nuclear-reactor-physics-1st-edition-9780123706317-0123706319